# Adding a line break to a UITextView

Tags: utf-8, nsstring, uitextview, whitespace

I have a `UITextView` that takes an `NSString` with formatting `stringWithUTF8String`. It is getting its values from a database and I want the text in the database to be rendered with breaks within the text. I tried using `\n` to do this but it gets rendered as text. Doing this in my information page of the app as straight text worked but I think the reason its not working when taking it from the database is because of the formatting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've heard `\n\n` works. Try that.

Comment: Sounds like your string has an actual "blackslash n" in it instead of a proper carriage return character.

Comment: I've done both \n and \n\n and both get rendered as text. thanks though. Anybody else?

Comment: Try when you make your have you tried something like this: `_label.text = @"Line 1\n" @"Line 2\n" @"Line 3";`

Comment: My turn. Take the NSString and replace all @"\\n" with @"\n".

Comment: @thyrgle: the text is coming from a database and cannot be broke up into lines

Comment: @No on in particular: I tried \n, never tried \\n

Comment: This isn't an "answer", but because of how the comments were becoming a thread... was maintaining some code, had this problem, and the underlying problem was that some fields were `UITextField` and some were `UITextView`... the *fields were the one that misbehaved.

Answer (score 102):

If you want to add newline in Xcode5 / Xcode6 storyboard Attribute-Inspector (AI), you do it this way:

1. Drag out a UITextView.
2. Double-click it to edit text, place cursor where you want the paragraph break.
3. Hit **alt-Enter** a couple of times to create a blank line & paragraph.

Or, CTRL + Return make a new line.

You can now see the effect into output / View-mode in storyboard.[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed. What to do now?

Comment: Use the text field in the attribute inspector instead of double tapping the field in storyboard, alt+Enter won't crash there.

Comment: control + return is the key

Comment: This is not the answer to the question actually asked!!

Comment: This worked for me:-

           remarkTextView.isEditable = true;
            remarkTextView.text = remarks;
            remarkTextView.isEditable = false;

Answer (score 39):

Expanding tc's answer a bit: when you have newlines in the string, you probably want to convert them to `\n` (that is, `@"\\n"` in Cocoa) then save to the database and, on getting the string BACK from the database, you probably want to convert those back to newlines.  So you'd use code something like this:

```
NSString *saveString = [myTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @"\\n"];
// save it to the db
// ... later ...
NSString *dbString = // get the string from the db.
myTextField.text = [dbString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\n" withString: @"\n"];
```

Comment: Tommecpe made a good point in an edit proposal - it is stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString - see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:

Comment: I think this is smart way of cheating to get it odne

Answer (score 26):

Simply the below:

```
{
textView.text = @"January: 7th,21st,\n February: 4th,18th,\n March: 4th,18th,\n April: 1st, 15th, 29th, \n May: 13th, 27th, \n June: 10th,24th, \n July: 8th, 22nd, \n August: 5th, 19th, \n September: 2nd, 16th, 30th, \n October: 14th, 28th, \n November: 11th, 25th";
        NSLog (@"Recycle Dates for Abbey Way");

}
```

will be out putted as below in your textView or whatever you choose

**Output :**

January: 7th, 21st,

February: 4th, 18th,

March: 4th, 18th etc etc

Answer (score 13):

In Swift, just add "\n" between two strings

**Example:**

```
let firstString = "Hello"

let secondString = "Senorita"

textview.text = firstString + "\n" + "secondString"
```

Comment: Worked fine for me. No need for \\n.

Answer (score 7):

I think, you should try using "\r".

I have tested it on Xcode 4.2.1, iOS 4.3

Edit: This also works in iOS 3.0 and iOS 5.1

Comment: Did you try using \n instead?

Answer (score 4):

when you get from db. try

```
NSString *content = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
self.textView.text = content;
```

Answer (score 2):

A UITextView will take the newlines, but it will not work with cariage returns.
You will have to make sure your input is correct.

I tried it in the IB editor, and had some troubles with it initially.
Then I used a text editor, typed my text and then pasted it into the IB editor.

That did the trick, for me.
Your source comes from a database, so I think probaly the newlines are actually newlines, but perhaphs carriage return's or other. Check the HEX string of your input.

Comment: Good answer. I copied over text from the text editor and the new lines showed up fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set the (UIKeyboardType)keyboardType and (UIReturnKeyTYpe) returnKeyType

if you are building in code.

If you are using IB then just go to the first inspector panel and set the TextInputTraits

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting the text from web, make sure you put a space before and after the /n
that solved my problem

as example (php):

```
echo $item_detail['item_title']."  \n ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Olie's answer... In Swift the code for updating the string from the database is:

```
let dbString = // get the string from the db.
myTextField.text = dbString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\\\n", withString: "\n")
```

Took me a while to figure out, so thought I would share.

Answer (score 0):

Append a character("\n") in the string

`var logs = "this is first Line"`
`self.logs.append(Character("\n"))`
`self.textView.text = self.logs`

Answer (score -2):

You're saving a literal "\n" in the database. Try saving a newline.