# How to change line in the UITextView with xib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I use UITextView to hold some infomation, and I have edited the text in the .xib file. The line will be changed when the current line has no space. The problem is that I don`t not how to change line when I want to. Look at the pic below:

[image]

I have try to use "\n" or "\\n", but it is displayed as text. I want to know how can I change line in the .xib file?

Comment: sorry, there seems something wrong with pic upload....

Comment: Try '\r'  or '\\\n'

Answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697253/adding-a-line-break-to-a-uitextview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work...

```
textView.text=@"Ankit \r Srivastava";
```

this should give you both the words in different rows...