# iOS UITextView ignoring newline char from JSON Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uitextview

I need to display some data from a JSON Webservice in my iOS App inside a UITextView which is multiline however when I use the String on the textview the new lines do not work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// Data Value from JSON = testing the data value \r\n Another \n liine maybe?
NSString *responseDataString = [dictRequestorDetails objectForKey:@"data"];
txtWorkflowDetails.text = responseDataString;
```

When I execute this code the UITextField shows

> testing the data value \r\n Another \n liine maybe?

However If I type in the string like

```
// Data Value from JSON = testing the data value \r\n Another \n liine maybe?
NSString *responseDataString = [dictRequestorDetails objectForKey:@"data"];
txtWorkflowDetails.text = @"testing the data value \r\n Another \n liine maybe?";
```

The line breaks then work in the TextView

Answer (score 3):

Just followed this post: [Adding a line break to a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697253/adding-a-line-break-to-a-uitextview)

I updated my JSON feed to output the new lines like

> testing the data value \nAnother \nmline maybe?

And then in my code ran;

```
responseDataString = [responseDataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

```
let stringForUITextView = originJsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the string first and replace all occurrences of \n with \n

```
NSString *newString = [responseDataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is txtWorkflowDetails set to allow Line Breaks (e.g. Word Wrap)?