# \n in JSON, tored in core data, not breaking lines in UITextView

Tags: ios, json

At the server, I have a string of text that is concatenated together and has `\n` added to create line breaks. This is done in `VB.net` as a string object.

This string is that added to a dictionary which is then available as a `JSON webservice.`

On my iOS app, I am reading the `JSON` and parsing it, saving the contents to core data.

when I display my text in a `UITextView` the string "hello\nthere" is shown exactly like that with no line breaks and the \n visible.

what have I done wrong?

I have also tried \r instead.

should I be making a string in the `vb.net` part like this "hello\nthere" - is that valid, or should I be using "hello" & vbcrlf & "there" and letting the JSON parser convert the line break to \n (if it does this)

or is the problem in the iOS side?

Comment: Whether `\n` means a line break or just the two characters `\` and `n` depends on context. Any JSON encoding mechanism should be able to mask line breaks correctly by itself.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the iOS-app and checking the string? It might have been escaped somewhere, resulting in "\\n" (probably somewhere around core-data). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697253/adding-a-line-break-to-a-uitextview

Comment: sorry for not replying i was on holiday then busy. i will try these suggestions now

Comment: thanks patric - it had indeed escaped it making \\n. using entity.fielname = [thetext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\n" withString: @"\n"];

to save to core data (obvioslu not the real entity, field or variable names btw) has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

can't see how else to mark this as complete - but please see the comment from – patric.schenke May 31 at 9:51

he was indeed corerct - the text had escaped to \n so replacing this with \n and saving that to core data has solved the issue.