# IOS - fit image and textView IB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uitextview, autolayout

I am new to IOS. I have a ViewController in which i add a Container in it. Then there is another ViewController in which i have a image and after the image there is a text view. The problem i am facing is when i run this app on Iphone 5 everything works perfect But when i run the app on Iphone 4s, the space grey bar appear between image and textView.I dont know how can I resolve this issue.

here are the images 
[image]   [image]

I want to ask one thing more is I want to start the text in textView after two or three line breaks from top.How can i start a text after some line breaks starting from top?

Comment: For adding line break in textview check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697253/adding-a-line-break-to-a-uitextview). Hope help you out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using auto-layout if you are using autolayout else try autoresizing for the views as iPhone 5 is 4-inch (320*568) display and iPhone 4s is 3.5-inch (320*480). So the issue is because of the different resolutions.

Comment: so as far as i understand what you are saying is i should have two images. one for iphone 4S and one for iPhone5 right? if i am not using autolayout ? so can you tell me if i am using this size 320×345 pixels  of image for iphone5. then what should be the size for iphone 4 ?

Comment: Check this... http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2